# Find all shortest paths using TraversalDescription

Tags: java, neo4j, graph-traversal

I need to find all all shortest paths between two nodes using [TraversalDescription](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/3.1/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/traversal/TraversalDescription.html).

(I cannot use Cypher procedure allShortestPaths() because I need to add some specific evaluator later:
[Neo4J: shortest paths with specific relation types sequence constrain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43002965/neo4j-shortest-paths-with-specific-relation-types-sequence-constrain)
)

```
Node startNode = ...;
Node endNode = ...;
TraversalDescription td = graphDb.traversalDescription()
    .breadthFirst()
    .evaluator(Evaluators.endNodeIs(Evaluation.INCLUDE_AND_PRUNE,
                                    Evaluation.EXCLUDE_AND_CONTINUE,
                                    endNode));

for (Path path : td.traverse(startNode)) {
    // only 1 path found
}
```

I get only 1 path.

But if I run the Cypher query:

```
MATCH (startNode{...})
MATCH (endNode{...})
MATCH path = allShortestPaths((startNode)-[*]-(endNode))
RETURN path;
```

There are more then one paths found for the same startNode and endNode.

How to set up the TraversalDescription to find all (shortest) paths?

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions:

1. Take a look at how `shortestpath` and `allshortestpths` are [actually implemented](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/72f72c5d75ae539ada88a25e42771a95c2919e51/community/graph-algo/src/main/java/org/neo4j/graphalgo/impl/path/ShortestPath.java). You may be able to modify a copy of the code to do what you want.
   [TraversaDescription](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/3.1/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/traversal/TraversalDescription.html) is not used at all.
2. There is also an "experimental" [BidirectionalTraversalDescription](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/3.1/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/traversal/BidirectionalTraversalDescription.html) that seems to be closer to the design of the `shortestpath` and `allshortestpths` implementations. You might be able to use that instead.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I tried to use the `BidirectionalTraversalDescription`, and even got the result, but suffered from significant performance issues:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43526585/neo4j-set-up-bidirectionaltraversaldescription-for-shortest-paths-search

Answer (score 0):

the root of your problem is "prune". You stop traversing when you find a first path with endPoint. So try this:

```
TraversalDescription td = graphDb.traversalDescription()
    .breadthFirst()
    .evaluator(Evaluators.endNodeIs(Evaluation.INCLUDE_AND_CONTINUE,
                                    Evaluation.EXCLUDE_AND_CONTINUE,
                                    endNode));
```

Comment: I use 'INCLUDE_AND_PRUNE' to specify that path (startNode)-(n1)-...-(nN)-(endNode) is a _good path_ and any elongation of that path (...-(nN)-(endNode)-(nK)-...) cannot be a _good path_. Your advice only can to reduce performance, but does not bring any good effect.

Answer (score 0):

My TraversalDescription cannot be used to find more than 1 path because of default `Uniqueness.NODE_GLOBAL`: once discovered, the end node will never be visited again.

So, the **1-st step** is to do:

```
td = td.uniqueness(Uniqueness.NODE_PATH);
```

But now we don't have a stop condition and traversal returns not only shortest paths.

**2-nd step** is to add path evaluator that brings a stop condition:

```
class EndNodeAndNotDeeperEvaluator implements Evaluator
{
    int depth = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    Node endNode;

    public EndNodeAndNotDeeperEvaluator(Node node) {
        endNode = node;
    }

    @Override
    public Evaluation evaluate(Path path) {
        if (path.length() > depth)
            return Evaluation.EXCLUDE_AND_PRUNE;

        if (path.endNode().equals(endNode)) {
            depth = path.length();
            return Evaluation.INCLUDE_AND_PRUNE;
        }

        return Evaluation.EXCLUDE_AND_CONTINUE;
    }
}

td = td.evaluator(new EndNodeAndNotDeeperEvaluator(endNode));
```

Now it works! ...for short paths (length < 10)
But for more long paths it does not give any result, but gives OutOfMemoryException.

This is because a lot of obviously not shortest paths are being investigated.

**3-rd step**: We need to make sure that each intermediate node is not encountered at the previous levels:

```
public class EndNodeAndNotDeeperEvaluator implements Evaluator
{
    private Node endNode;
    private Map<Long,Integer> nodeDepths = new HashMap(100000);

    public EndNodeAndNotDeeperEvaluator(Node node) {
        endNode = node;
    }

    @Override
    public Evaluation evaluate(Path path) {
        Node pEndNode = path.endNode();

        Integer nodeDepth = nodeDepths.get(pEndNode.getId());
        if (nodeDepth == null) {
            nodeDepths.put(pEndNode.getId(), path.length());
        }
        else if (path.length() > nodeDepth) {
            return Evaluation.EXCLUDE_AND_PRUNE;
        }

        if (pEndNode.equals(endNode)) {
            //System.err.println(" map.size="+nodeDepths.size());
            return Evaluation.INCLUDE_AND_PRUNE;
        }

        return Evaluation.EXCLUDE_AND_CONTINUE;
    }
}
```

And **now it works** for all shortest paths that I have.
*But not very quickly*... For longest paths (length=81) it takes about 6700ms...
While the usual traversal with `Uniqueness.NODE_GLOBAL` takes 550ms (finds only first path);
And the built in `GraphAlgoFactory.shortestPath(...).findAllPaths(...)` takes 90ms!